# custom spring namespace handlers in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am working through the tutorials on writing custom spring namespace handlers found here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/extensible-xml.html

Everything was working great until I got to section B.5 on registering the new handler and schema..

I have tried putting spring.handlers and spring.schemas into my project - didn't work

I was able to find the File | Settings | Schemas and DTD's, which did enable the auto-complete in the editor, but the handler is still not registering.  Also this did not translate to an entry in the spring.schemas file.

In short, can someone explain how to do the following in intelliJ 11.1.2?

a) configure it to recognize the new schema and namespace handler
b) put the correct information into the META-INF/spring.handlers and spring.schemas files when I build the artifact?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "handler is still not registering"? You mean, it isn't launched at runtime, or isn't honored in the editor? In the first case, please check that your module output directories contains the handler class files and META-INF/spring.{handlers,schemas}. In the second case, have you tried first compiling everything and then invoking 'Parse custom bean' intention action in the editor?

Comment: It's the first.  The editor is honoring my custom namespace, but the META-INF directory is not being put into the output directory.  How do I tell intelliJ to include the META-INF directory?  It's in the src/main/resources right now...  I tried putting a copy into src/test/resources to no avail.

Comment: Please check resource patterns in Settings | Compiler and ensure that spring.handlers and spring.schemas are accepted by that pattern. Please also ensure that src/main/resources is marked as a source root in module path settings.

Comment: had to add *.handlers, *.schemas, and *.xsd.  Will post as an accepted answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make this work, I needed to add *.handlers, *.schemas, and *.xsd to the resource patterns (Settings | Compiler).  Once I got that setup, it worked like a charm.